# Can't access kubernetes nodeport service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, minikube, api-gateway

I don't think I miss anything, but my angular app doesn't seem to be able to contact the service I exposed trough Kubernetes.

Whenever I try to call the exposed nodeport on my localhost, I get a connection refused.

The deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: society-api-gateway-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: society-api-gateway-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: society-api-gateway-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: society-api-gateway-deployment
        image: tbusschaert/society-api-gateway:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: society-api-gateway-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: society-api-gateway-deployment
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30001
```

I double checked, the call doesn't reach my pod, and this is the error I get when going the call:

[image]

I'm using minikube and kubectl on my local machine.

I'm out of options, tried everything I though it could be, thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

So after following the suggestions, i used the node IP to call the service:

[image]

I changed the IP in my angular project, now I get a connection timeout:

[image]

As for the port forward, I get a permission error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I thought, the problem was related to minikube not opening up to my localhost.

First of all I didn't need a NodePort, but the LoadBalancer also fit my need, so my API gateway became a LoadBalancer.

Second, when using minikube, to achieve what I wanted ( running kubernetes on my local machine and my angular client also being on my local machine ), you have to create a minikube tunnel, exactly how they explain it here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#run-tunnel-in-a-separate-terminal

Comment: That's very strange. Using `minikube tunnel` instead of `minikube service <name>` works for me as well. It's strange, because the tutorial I was following was using `minikube service` without issues. Also' when running `minikube service` it opens my browser, but gets an `ERR: CONNECTION REFUSED` which indicates something is off.

Answer (score 1):

From doc, you see that the templeate will be like this `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.

So first, From `kubectl get node -o wide` comamnd take the `NodeIP`.
then try with the `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`. For example, If the NodeIP is `172.19.0.2` then try `172.19.0.2:30001` with your sub url.

Or, Another way is with port-forwarding. In a terminal first try port-forwarding with `kubectl port-forward svc/society-api-gateway-service 80:80`. Then use the url you have tried with `localhost`.

Comment: used the NodeIP to make the calls, get another error now ( edit original post to show the procedure ). I tried port forwarding , get a permission error, also shown in edit.

Comment: `kubectl port-forward svc/society-api-gateway-service 8081:80` try with a different local port. local port 80 is already in use thats why you got this error

Comment: one more thing, it looks like your server is listening to  only ipv6 connections

Comment: Maybe I should specify, that I'm using minikube (I run the cluster on my dev machine, and the angular app is not deployed on kubernetes, it's straight from the IDE). I'll try the port forward and keep u up to date

Comment: **@Emon46** may be right. Can you make sure your application is listening on IPv4 ?